# Trying to use USB guitar cord in Windows 7

Tags: recording, fl-studio

I was given an Ibanez Acoustic/Electric for Christmas. I don't think it was brand new, but it looks and sounds great. I want to use this:
[image]

Which I got from Amazon for like $12.

When I plugged it into my usb port, the windows drivers installed themselves, and I can "see" it in my list of recording devices:

[image]

Trouble is, the level indicator shown in the above picture does not indicate activity.
I've gone into the properties of that device and checked/adjusted everything I can find to no avail. The computer is "listening to this device," The levels are at 100%, I've tried various combinations of "Exclusive Mode," If I plug the guitar directly into my amp (with a normal 1/4" plug), the amp picks up the guitar. I've tried various combos of disabling other sound devices, too.

The goal is to use FL Studio to record, but I'm pretty sure that the problem is in Windows as indicated by the indicator showing no activity. In FL Studio I'm using Asio4all and I see the USB cord listed on my mixer as an input option.

My computer is windows 7 64 bit, and I've tried FL Studio 11 in 64 bit mode and 32.

**Ideas?**

Edit: The red LED on the usb jack blinks steady about twice per second. Maybe someone knows what that means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All guitar link type cables require the correct drivers to be installed and set up. They do not generally work straight out of the box, and ASIO4ALL doesn't generally identify them correctly.

Look in your documentation that came with the cable and identify the drivers and setup process you need (they are all a bit different)

The sound quality from these is not great, they don't compare to having a decent soundcard and normal guitar lead.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've seen a few YouTube vids that show this cord working right out of the box, and due to the fact that I got no documentation (only the cord in a bag), I was really hoping that I didn't need anything additional. I'm now returning it and am strongly considering [this](https://www.amazon.com/BEHRINGER-Audio-Interface-1-Channel-UM2/dp/B00EK1OTZC/ref=pd_cp_267_2?pd_rd_w=qFSRo&pf_rd_p=ef4dc990-a9ca-4945-ae0b-f8d549198ed6&pf_rd_r=3631FMWX7J8769W4WNRQ&pd_rd_r=13829913-0e27-11e9-8165-45849ee12971&pd_rd_wg=7e8cd&pd_rd_i=B00EK1OTZC&psc=1&refRID=3631FMWX7J8769W4WNRQ). Better?

Comment: That's not a bad starter audio interface. Yes.